# How to print a image file in printer

Tags: javascript, image, printing

I write a simple program to print a image in JSF....

I have one image (sampleImage.png).. Already i connected my pc to printer....

Manually i open the image and select print option , then i got image from printer....

Now i want print image using javascript....

File name : imagePrint.jsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Printer</title>          
        <script type="text/javascript">
             function printImage()
            {                                       
               // Here i want write a script for print image                              
            }
        </script>
```

```
    <body>
        <h:form id="fileViewerForm">
            <rich:panel>
                <f:facet name="header">
                    <h:outputText value="Printer"/>
                </f:facet>

                <h:commandButton value="PrintImage" onclick="printImage();"/>

                   <rich:panel id="imageViewerPanel">                               
                       <h:graphicImage id="imageViewer" value="sampleImage.png" url="sampleImage.png"/>             
                  </rich:panel>                                       
            </rich:panel>
        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
```

help me about this..

The following script for print the textarea into the printer.....
So i need to print the image

```
            function printText()
            {
                alert("Text Area print to printer start....");
                var textElem = document.getElementById("fileViewerForm:textAreaGrid1").innerHTML;
                alert("Text Area Content : " + textElem);

                if(textElem.toLowerCase().indexOf("<textarea", 0) != -1)
                {
                    textElem = document.getElementById("fileViewerForm:fileContent1").value;
                    var regExp = /\n/gi;
                    textElem = textElem.replace(regExp,'<br>');
                }
                popup = window.open('','popup','toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=200,height=150');
                popup.document.open();
                popup.document.write("<html><head></head><body onload='print()'>");
                popup.document.write(textElem);
                popup.document.write("</body></html>");
                popup.document.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will receive image id using both
 h:form and h:graphicImage tag id's

The Java script is :

```
 function printImage()         
 {            
   var iamgeId = document.getElementById('fileViewerForm:imageViewer');

   var imagObject = new Image();
   imagObject = iamgeId;
   var originalImage = '<img id="imageViewer" src="'+imagObject.src+'" 
                        height="'+imagObject.height+'"
                         width="'+imagObject.width+'" />';

   popup =  window.open('','popup','toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=200,height=150');
   popup.document.open();
   popup.document.write("<html><head></head><body onload='print()'>");
   popup.document.write(originalImage);
   popup.document.write("</body></html>");
   popup.document.close();           
}
```

JSF code is :

```
  <h:commandButton value="Print" onclick="printImage();"/><br>
       <rich:panel id="imageViewerPanel">                

            <h:graphicImage id="imageViewer" url="sampleImage.png"
                            value="sampleImage.png" width="200"
                                                     height="200" />
       </rich:panel>
  </h:panelGrid>
```

It works on FireFox 3.0.18.

By,
 Eswara Moorthy, NEC.

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to print using javascript, since you can't manage hardware devices from the browser and it executes there.

Comment: thanks for ur response...                   
Now u may see my post again...
already iwrote a script for print the text area content...

Answer (score 0):

You could send this to the browser

```
   window.print();
```

It is up to the browser to decide what to do.

To print specific portions of the page, consider a print stylesheet. Using the `media` attribute allows you to make a certain file print only styles.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/print.css" media="print" />
```

Comment: hi, This method is used to print full window...
But i need to print only specific image..
for example, in my page have logo... So i need to take only the logo, not full content of the page...

Comment: i am new one of this. i can't understand this...
What content i write into the css file...