# Print a specific image from webpages without popup window or new window?

Tags: javascript, html, printing

Is there any possible to print a specific image from webpages without popup window or new window?

Suppose i have four images in my application. Just i need to print second image only.
And also i want to implement large page like some textarea, some text box, more images etc...

So many code available with pop up window or new window.

please help me about this.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Combine [print stylesheets](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) with [alternative stylesheets](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/alternate/).

Comment: how to acheive? Please give me a sample code or reference links.

Comment: Related question url with code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742144/how-to-print-a-image-file-in-printer

Comment: My answer already has links in it to articles explaining the techniques. Putting them together isn't difficult.

Comment: I saw ur post(question and answer). But you have 49 pages. I feel to difficult to found related answer for me.. Please give me the page number or url.

Comment: The links in the **answer** to your question to which these comments are connected! There are two of them! Not 49 pages of them! Not the links in my profile to questions I have answered!

Comment: Another one doubt. Suppose i have textarea with 100 lines of content.
Suppose i select statically like first 10 or 50-60 or specific lines. This kind of recruitment acheived by css. But In case, i don't know, the user select dynamically  for how many no of lines in textarea using cursor, Is there any possible to acheive via CSS. Or any other way?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask, or how it is related to to this answer or the question.

Comment: k..I have complete to print the image using stylesheet for ur reference url.. Now i practise to print the textarea content.
i can easy to print the whole textarea content using stylesheet.

Comment: That's a completely different question and should be asked as such (not suck as a comment on an unrelated question). As a rule of thumb though, if the purpose of some content is for printing, then it probably shouldn't be in a textarea in the first place - those are for taking input from users.

Comment: k..I will try to correct my mistakes. In future i will ask the questions right way.