# Send barcode image / data to client' s barcode writer from a java web application

Tags: java, web-applications, printing, barcode

I need to send generated barcode image (or the string data) generated by [barbecue](http://barbecue.sourceforge.net/) to client's barcode writer (model: Argox OS-214+). I think I can use javascript or an external applet, but I'm not sure how to make it. Does anyone suggest a method especially for this model barcode writer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do bits generated by you have to travel to reach the printer?

Comment: well, I display generated barcode on a jsf page, I just need to print it over, with browser support (primarily) or with an applet.

Comment: Will a javascript snippet telling the browser to print be sufficient?

Comment: window.print() doesn' t satisfy me at all, because i only want to send barcode's image to printer. date, page name or page numbers shouldn't be printed.

Comment: Then you need to figure out how to print what you want - modern applets can talk to the windows printer using the javax.print API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, then.

[How to print a image file in printer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2742144/how-to-print-a-image-file-in-printer) fairly resolved my problem, I've sent data as image from javascript and configure the printer settings for other details.

Thanks everyone!